Representations of compact connected Lie groups
Is there a one-to-one correspondence between finite-dim. representations of compact connected (matrix) Lie groups and finite-dim. representations of their Lie algebras? More specifically, I try to understand if we can obtain Lie group representations by exponentiating a Lie algebra representation $\rho$.
I understand that exp is surjective in the described case, but infectivity is not necessary: So, if exp$(X)=$exp$(X')$, does it necessarily imply exp$(\rho(X)) = $exp$(\rho(X'))$?

Did you work out the case of $S^1$? What did you find?

In general we only have this correspondence for simply connected Lie groups $G$ (with no assumptions about compactness). If $G$ is connected but not simply connected, then its universal cover $\widetilde{G}$ sits inside a short exact sequence
$$1 \to \pi_1(G) \to \widetilde{G} \to G \to 1$$
and then the correspondence is that finite-dimensional representations of the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ exponentiate to finite-dimensional representations of the universal cover $\widetilde{G}$, and this is an equivalence of categories. Among these, the representations of $G$ are the representations of $\widetilde{G}$ on which the fundamental group $\pi_1(G)$ acts trivially.
As Moishe Kohan says in the comments, it's a good exercise to work out what this looks like explicitly for $G = S^1$. The next simplest example, which is also a good exercise, is $G = SO(3)$.
